# How to take the output of permutation into a list

Tags: python, list, recursion, permutation

I've got this code that outputs all permutations for a given word:

```
def get_permutation(word, base = ""):
    
    if len(word) == 0:
        print(base)
    
    for i in range(len(word)):
        
        newBase = base + word[i]
        newWord = word[0:i] + word[i + 1:]
        
        get_permutation(newWord, newBase)
```

I want to have the output saved into a list that gets returned after this function ends.
This is probably easy, but I'm a beginner with python so I don't know how

Comment: I assume you're looking for a general technique for this, and that the actual problem you're solving here doesn't matter? Because if you just want permutations, you should use `itertools.permutations` from the standard library.

Comment: Yeah I want the technique

Comment: Are you aware of appending to lists? And returning values from functions? If not, those are very fundamental facets of Python, so I recommend reading a basic Python book and taking some beginner tutorials so that you have the base knowledge that would help you with all your future programs.

Comment: Do you understand what `return` is for? Would you be able to collect results into a list for a *non*-recursive algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single function that returns the whole list, with everything enclosed it can be done as follows.

```py
def get_permutations_list(word, base = ""):    

    lst = [] #Create a list to hold permutations.

    def get_permutation(word, base):

        if len(word) == 0:
            lst.append(base) #Add current permutation to end of list.

        for i in range(len(word)):

            newBase = base + word[i]
            newWord = word[0:i] + word[i + 1:]

            get_permutation(newWord, newBase)

    get_permutation(word, base) #Run the recursive function.
    
    return lst #Return the completed list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reached an answer:

```
answer = [ ]

def get_permutation(word, base = ""):
    
    if len(word) == 0:
        answer.append(base)
    
    for i in range(len(word)):
        
        newBase = base + word[i]
        newWord = word[0:i] + word[i + 1:]
        
        get_permutation(newWord, newBase)
    
    return answer
```

Only problem is that the list is printed vertically?